# Change marker color in Google Maps V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to change the color of a marker.

I have this:

```
private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, double lat, double lon,
                         int title, int snippet) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                                     .title(getString(title))
                                     .snippet(getString(snippet)));
```

and then this to add a marker:

```
addMarker(map, 40.748963847316034, -73.96807193756104,
                R.string.title, R.string.snippet);
```

I want to change the color of the marker and I thought it would be easy and just implement it like this:

```
private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, double lat, double lon,
                         int title, int snippet, int icon) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                                     .title(getString(title))
                                     .snippet(getString(snippet))
                                         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.(getString(icon)));
```

and:

```
addMarker(map, 40.748963847316034, -73.96807193756104,
                R.string.title, R.string.snippet, HUE_AZURE);
```

But I can't use "getString" together with ".icon" apparently.

How can I do this?

Also, is that method of changing color supported for API 8+? I've had lots of problems supporting API 8+ and it would suck if this broke something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a loop where I set markers with different colors on the map and it works great for me:

```
for (Task tempTask : TasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository())
                {
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(tempTask.getLatitude(), tempTask.getLongtitude());
                    if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_WAITING))
                    {
                        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_blue)));
                    }
                    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS))
                    {
                        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_bordo)));
                    }
                    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_ON_THE_WAY))
                    {
                        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_turkiz)));
                    }
                    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_COMPLETE))
                    {
                        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_orange)));
                    }
                    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_FAILED))
                    {
                        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_purpul)));
                    }
}
```

See if it's helps you.

The if statements are for changing the marker icon.

Comment: I need some way of getting the icon to work like the position/title/snippet in my code, with getString.

Comment: but the image of the icon is not a string but a resource. so you should get it using the BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource method.

Comment: Sorry for being really slow but how would i implement that in my current code here?
  for the title and snippet I use .title(getString(title))

what would I use for .icon?

Comment: if "int icon" is the resource id of your icon, then you should do: BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)

Comment: Ok, .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)) seems to be working, but what should I put in the "addMarker" now? For the title and snippte I write R.string.title/snippet, what do i put there if I want HUE_AZURE for example? Thanks so much for the help by the way :)

Comment: is HUE_AZURE is your resource?

Comment: HUE_AZURE is just the name of the color I use, I didn´t add it. Normally I would use .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)) But that wont work with my code

Comment: If you check the code on this site under "change the default marker" [Android Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Comment: from the documentation: "or set a custom marker color with the BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(float hue) method. The hue is a value between 0 and 360, representing points on a color wheel". So you basiclly can pass a float number between 0 -360

Comment: When I change "int icon" to "float icon" at "private void addMarker" "fromResource" shows an error, because "fromResource" uses an int.

EDIT: changed "fromResource" to "defaultMarker" and it worked! Thanks man, I wish I could pay you back in some way more than just marking as correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

The following snippet does the trick for me without dependencies:

```
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);

myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .icon(bitmapDescriptor)
    .title(point.toString()));
```

Found it here: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2013/01/change-marker-color-of-googlemaps-v2.html

Comment: Thanks you, that's perfect for who are lazy and want to using default marker, change color just call marker.setIcon(bitmapDescriptor); :D